# Horizontal scrolling in nano editor?

Tags: editors, nano

I am using nano on files with long lines.
How could I scroll the nano window horizontally?

Ex:

```
┌────────────┐
|Lorem ipsum |dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
|sed do eiusm|od tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
|Dolor sed vi|verra ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum enim.
|In massa tem|por nec feugiat. Nunc aliquet bibendum enim facilisis gravida. 
└────────────┘
```

I would like scrolling right side:

```
            ┌────────────┐
Lorem ipsum |dolor sit am|et, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
sed do eiusm|od tempor in|cididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
Dolor sed vi|verra ipsum |nunc aliquet bibendum enim.
In massa tem|por nec feug|iat. Nunc aliquet bibendum enim facilisis gravida. 
            └────────────┘
```

Comment: +1, but I suspect the answer is "you can't", and the better answer is "use vim". (And the slightly less better answer is "use emacs". :p)

Comment: +1, also because I appreciate ASCII art ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you cannot do that in `nano`. The closest you could get would be line wrapping, precisely "soft wrapping": <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>$</kbd>.

This will wrap lines so you could see them all on the screen.

<sub>*Source: https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.9/nano.html (search for --softwrap)*</sub>

You could get this kind of behaviour with `vim`, though, the editor is more configurable. See: https://ddrscott.github.io/blog/2016/sidescroll/

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>$</kbd> wasn't working for me. Not sure if OS or shell matters (I'm on Mac using `zsh`) but I found something else that worked:

<kbd>^</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> for `JUSTIFY`. Not side-scrolling, but since OP accepted soft-wrapping and I believe this does the same thing, leaving this answer here for people who don't have success with the accepted answer.